# to sleep + listening / to sleep + while + listening

Tags: grammar

> "Go to sleep listening to this song, it helps you relax."
>   "Go to sleep while listening to this song, it helps you relax."

Do they mean the same? Or do they have differences in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

These two sentences do essentially carry the same meaning.

> "Go to sleep listening to this song, it helps you relax."
>   "Go to sleep *while* listening to this song, it helps you relax."

The word "while" does clarify that you mean for these two things to happen at the same time - listening *and* going to sleep. In some other situations it may be necessary to make that clear, but it is not needed in this example.

Were the sentence phrased differently you may need to include "while":

> Listen to this song *and* go to sleep.

Even though "and" *can* link two things occurring at the same time (eg "let's sit and eat"), it isn't *completely clear* that you mean for the song to be listened to while you go to sleep. It *could* mean that you listen to the song first, and then you go to sleep. So in this situation it would be better phrased as:

> Listen to this song *while* going to sleep.